# Is there any specific relationship among the determinant of leading principal submatrices of a tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

The following symmetric matrix $A$ is given. Let denote $A_i$ the $i$-th leading principal submatrix of the matrix $A$.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
b_1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
& b_2 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} \\
& & & b_{n-1} & a_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The determinant of the matrix $A$ is given by the recurrence relation

$det(A_i) = a_i det(A_{i-1}) - b_{i-1}^2det(A_{i-2})$

I would like to know is there any other relation among the determinant of the leading principal submatrix of $A$? for example a numerically  that determines determinant of $A_j$ is greater than $A_m$ for $j > m$ or any thing else.